# How can I link to a specific tab in crm-ui-tab-set

Tags: angular

With AngularJS, I have a page (created with `civix generate:angular-page`) that includes a set of tabs like so:

```
  <div crm-ui-tab-set>
    <div id="mytab1" crm-ui-tab crm-title="ts('Tab 1')">
      This is Tab 1.
    </div>
    <div id="mytab2" crm-ui-tab crm-title="ts('Tab 2')">
      This is Tab 2.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Let's say this page is at `/a/#/foo`. As far as I can tell, Tab 1 is the default tab and will always be opened when I open this URL, which is what I want most of the time. But sometimes I want that page to open in Tab 2.

How can I link to `/a/#/foo` in a way that Tab 2 is opened by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of writing (circa `4.7.20`), the `crm-ui-tab-set` directive does not support an option to manage the active tab.

I think a patch to support that would be welcome. For example, one might update `crm-ui-tab-set` (in `ang/crmUi.js`) to support an extra variable `active-tab` with an interface like this:

```
<div crm-ui-tab-set active-tab="selectedTab">
  <div id="mytab1" crm-ui-tab crm-title="ts('Tab 1')">
    This is Tab 1.
  </div>
  <div id="mytab2" crm-ui-tab crm-title="ts('Tab 2')">
    This is Tab 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

You could then initialize `selectedTab` from the controller, e.g.

```
angular...controller('MyController', function(...){
  $scope.selectedTab = "mytab1";
});
```

or

```
$routeProvider.when('/foo/{tabName}', {
   controller: 'MyController',
   resolve: {tabName: function($route){return route.current.params.tabName;}},
   ...
});

angular...controller('MyController', function(tabName, ...){
  $scope.selectedTab = tabName; // Ex: "mytab1", "mytab2"
});
```

**Observation**: `crm-ui-tab-set` is a thin wrapper for [jQueryUI `tabs`](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/). It's built with "jQuery Passhthrough" (`ui-jq="tabs"`) from `angular-ui-utils` (`v0.1.x`). Unfortunately, the docs/examples for "jQuery Passthrough" have been scrubbed from `angular-ui`'s website, but you can find some discussion in [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150515012057/http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq).

**Tip**: Given that `ui-jq` has been deprecated, we should try to limit/contain the jQuery-isms. `crm-ui-tab-set` would probably call some jQuery functions, but downstream extensions shouldn't.

**Tip**: If your UI is built on Bootstrap CSS, then consider replacing `crm-ui-tab-set` with [`uib-tabset` from `anguilar-ui-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: Thanks, Tim Otten. Issue with PR filed here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20692